# Phase shifting operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_phase_space#Phase-shifting_operator
operator of phase shift is defined as
$$U(\theta)=e^{-i\theta N}$$ where N is number operator.
How to prove that

$$A=U^*(\theta)aU(\theta)=ae^{-i\theta}$$

$a$ is anahillation operator

Ok, we have differentiate respect to theta we have as on wikipedia link 
$$ \frac{d}{d\theta}(U^{*}aU)=-iU^*aU$$

Solution of this differential equation is

$$U^*aU=e^{-i\theta}\neq ae^{-i\theta}$$

How ?

Answer (score 2):

A constructive way of looking at the solution is to see what happens under the rug. Before performing the actual calculation, we write-down some useful expressions for later use: $$\begin{array}{l}
\left[ {a,N} \right] = a,\\
\left[ {a,{N^2}} \right] = aN + Na.
\end{array}\tag{1}\label{comm}$$
The second commutation can be found by the use of the identity $\left[ {A,BC} \right] = B\left[ {A,C} \right] + \left[ {A,B} \right]C$.

Now the operator $A = {U^\dagger }\cdot a \cdot U$ is writtens in the form
$$\begin{align}
A & = {U^\dagger }\cdot a \cdot U, \\
  & = \exp \left( {i\theta N} \right) \cdot a \cdot \exp \left( { - i\theta N} \right), \\
  & = \left[ {1 + \left( {i\theta N} \right) + \frac{{{{\left( {i\theta N} \right)}^2}}}{{2!}} + \frac{{{{\left( {i\theta N} \right)}^3}}}{{3!}} +  ... } \right]  a  \left[ {1 + \left( { - i\theta N} \right) + \frac{{{{\left( { - i\theta N} \right)}^2}}}{{2!}} + \frac{{{{\left( { - i\theta N} \right)}^3}}}{{3!}} +  ... } \right]. \tag{2}\label{powerseries}
\end{align}
$$
We collect the powers of $\theta$ from Eq. \eqref{powerseries}, 
\begin{array}{l}
{\theta ^0}:a,\\
\\
{\theta ^1}: - ai\theta N + i\theta Na,\\
\\
{\theta ^2}:a\frac{{{{\left( { - i\theta N} \right)}^2}}}{{2!}} + i\theta Na\left( { - i\theta N} \right) + \frac{{{{\left( {i\theta N} \right)}^2}}}{{2!}}a. \tag{3} \label{thetas}
\end{array}

We massage each term as follows: 
\begin{align}
{\theta ^1}& :~ - ai\theta N + i\theta Na, \\
             & =  - i\theta \left( {aN - Na} \right), \\
             & =- i\theta a. \tag{4} \label{theta_1}
\end{align}
In the last line of the Eq. \eqref{theta_1}, we used the forst commutation in Eq. \eqref{comm}.

Now we take care of the second power of $\theta$ $-$
\begin{align}
{\theta ^2}& :a\frac{{{{\left( { - i\theta N} \right)}^2}}}{{2!}} + i\theta Na\left( { - i\theta N} \right) + \frac{{{{\left( {i\theta N} \right)}^2}}}{{2!}}a, \\
& = \frac{{{\theta ^2}}}{{2!}}\left( {2NaN - {N^2}a - a{N^2}} \right), \\
& = \frac{{{\theta ^2}}}{{2!}}\left( {NaN - {N^2}a + NaN - a{N^2}} \right), \\ 
& = \frac{{{\theta ^2}}}{{2!}}\left( {N\left[ {a,N} \right] + \left[ {N,a} \right]N} \right), \\
& = \frac{{{\theta ^2}}}{{2!}}\left( {Na - aN} \right), \\ 
& =  - a\frac{{{\theta ^2}}}{{2!}}, \\ 
& = a\frac{{{{\left( { - i\theta } \right)}^2}}}{{2!}}. \tag{5} \label{theta_2}
\end{align}

Here we have repeatedly used the first commutation in Eq. \eqref{comm}. Now we collect everything from Eqs. \eqref{thetas}, \eqref{theta_1} & \eqref{theta_2}, namely
$$\begin{align} A & = a + a\left( { - i\theta } \right) + a\frac{{{{\left( { - i\theta } \right)}^2}}}{{2!}} +  \cdots,  \\
& = a \cdot \exp\left( { - i\theta } \right).~~\left(\mathrm{QED}\right)
\end{align}$$

**Note**: The third power of $\theta$ has the same trend, although the calculation is a little cumbersome. In that calculation, you will need the second commutation in Eq. \eqref{comm}.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the constant of integration. The differential equation you have is $\frac{d}{d\theta}(U^{\ast}a U) = -i U^{\ast}a U \Rightarrow \ln(U^{\ast}a U) = -i \theta + ln C$ By solving the differential equation you get $C e^{-i \theta}$ where you can fix the constant, $C$, by using the condition $U^{\ast}a U= a$ at $\theta=0$.